# how to calculate each reduce time in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm tring to calculate each Reduce time.

I use three reducers. And I want to calculate each reduce.

> ex) reduce 0 : [elapsed time], reduce 1: [elapsed time], reduce 2:
>   [elapsed time].

Do I use `long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis()` ?

I don't know well how to calculate time..

Is there a method to solve it?

Comment: the Web UI of hadoop has information about the execution time of each task

Comment: Can I print each task using like `System.out.println`?

Comment: you can do sysout of total time of reducer by leveraging`setup()` and `cleanup()`. But Resource Manager web UI gives you inside application attempt.

Comment: I appreciate your advise!